# No puedo acceder a propiedades de base datos tempdb

Tags: sql, sql-server, server

¡Hola a todos!

Tengo el siguiente inconveniente, estoy intentando ingresar a la propiedad de mi BD Tempdb pero me devuelve el siguiente mensaje:

Tengo accesos de dba para realizar dicha operación.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Es posible que no tengas acceso explícito. ¿En qué punto del management studio te da ese error?

Comment: Al dar clic derecho --> propiedades y me devuelve ese mensaje.

Comment: Te da el mismo problema en otras bases de datos, como la máster o la msdb?
Es posible que necesites más permisos.

Comment: Hola, solo me sucede con la BD tempb.